# How can I set different sensitivities for two mice at the same time?

Tags: xorg, mouse, configuration, input-devices

I often use a USB mouse and my laptop's pointing stick at the same time. I can adjust the sensitivity in Mouse Preferences, but the sensitivities of the two mice are so different that I cannot find a compromise setting.

Is there a way to specify a different sensitivity setting for each mouse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [**xinput**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/xinput.1.html) to set the sensitivities/accels for the mice.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Macintosh mouse button emulation          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

From that output take the numeric `id` of the mice. I'll provide an example for my Logitech mouse. For multiple mice rinse and repeat.

So for my logitech I will use `xinput get-feedbacks <device name>` and `xinput set-ptr-feedback <device name> <threshold> <num> <denom>`

```
$ xinput get-feedbacks 8
1 feedback class
PtrFeedbackClass id=0
    accelNum is 3
    accelDenom is 10
    threshold is 4
```

The accel is set as a fraction so you need to set the nom and denom for it:

```
$ xinput set-ptr-feedback 8 4 3 1
$ xinput get-feedbacks 8
1 feedback class
PtrFeedbackClass id=0
    accelNum is 3
    accelDenom is 1
    threshold is 4
```

Comment: Works wonders. Now I'm just banging my head against [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xinput/+bug/507305).

Comment: Please update your bug report for natty if it still aint fixed :-S

Comment: Is this persisted between reboots?