# Mouse settings not restored after disconnecting external mouse

Tags: mouse, cursor

I have a Dell Inspiron 1545 with Ubuntu 11.04. When a connect an external mouse and then disconnect it, the cursor (using the touchpad) gets very slow. To fix it, I have to go to GPointing Device Settings->AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint->Speed and modify a bit the settings to obtain a faster cursor.

That happens every time I disconnect the external mouse. Is there a way to maintain the same settings?

By the way, GPointing Device Settings is what I get by opening the application "Poiting Devices".

This is the screenshot of the settings:

[image]

**UPDATE**: Actually, the settings are reset to the start configuration when I restart the operative system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be useful: [How do I make xinput mouse settings persistent for a USB mouse?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3899/how-do-i-make-xinput-mouse-settings-persistent-for-a-usb-mouse)

Comment: I can't speak to a Dell, but on my HP if I use the disable mouse button and re-enable it my settings come back when I have weirdness.