# Chrome/Chromium middle mouse button for scroll Linux, Mac

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Clicking the middle button doesn't allow me scroll the page. Is there any way to fix this behavior?

Information:

1. Ubuntu 10.10
2. **Chromium 9.0.597.94**
3. Logitech MX518

**Update**: also Chrome, and the other Chromium based ones.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In Linux based/Mac systems, Google Chrome / Chromium hasn't got this feature.
You have to get an extension, eg.: [[image: AutoScroll] AutoScroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan).

Comment: Great tip  - worked for me.

Comment: It's a real shame they don't have this in by default.

Comment: How do you control the speed?

Comment: Isn't it in settings?

Comment: Good answer, but why are you asking me to click on an image, and not just provide a regular link?

Comment: @mwfearnley, I've modified it just for you :)

Comment: This extension is blocking mouseDown event in some case's. And it can break some website's behaviour :( Example: it may be <span> what opening something in new tab.

Comment: @faiwer then report as a bug to the developer!

Comment: I saw the code. I think it isn't a bug. It's a feature of the approach. it doesn't wait for a mouse movement before it starts to scroll.

Comment: This answer is better and should be accepted: https://askubuntu.com/a/868173/37979

Comment: This works ok, however it is limited to websites with javascript enabled so some more security minded users would not like it very much. A system-wide alternative is available here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472398/can-i-make-middle-mouse-scrolling-behave-more-like-autoscrolling/472451#472451

Answer (score 33):

This will work with all your applications without the need of installing anything.

#### Get your input deviceId number

```
xinput list
```

To list available properties, use `xinput list-props $deviceId`. If you are using libinput (the future/present) almost all properties will start with *libinput* (also check `libinput list-devices`).

**Test**: You can always test your input devices with [`libinput debug-events`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/libinput.1.html), [`xev`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/xev.1.html), [`evtest`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/evtest.1.html), `evemu-record` or [`xinput --test $deviceId`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/xinput.1.html#options).

#### With [`libinput`](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/)

[Since 17.04](https://ubuntubudgie.org/blog/2017/04/11/17-04-release-notes) Ubuntu uses **libinput**, so to set mouse properties:

```bash
# xinput device option setting
xinput set-prop $deviceId "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 0, 0, 1  # _button_ as scroll method
xinput set-prop $deviceId "libinput Button Scrolling Button" 2      # Using middle buttpn. Already 2 by default

xinput set-prop $deviceId "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1    # OPTIONAL, for natural scrolling. You can also get this with gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll true
```

Description from [`man libinput`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man4/libinput.4.html):

> - **libinput Scroll Method Enabled** 3 boolean values (8 bit, 0 or 1), in order "two-finger", "edge", "button".  Indicates which scroll method is currently enabled on this device.
> - **libinput Button Scrolling Button** 1 32-bit value. Sets the button number to use for button scrolling. This setting is independent of the scroll method, to enable button scrolling the method must be set to button-scrolling and a valid button must be set.

#### With [`evdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102011)

```bash
xinput --set-prop $deviceId 'Evdev Wheel Emulation' 1
xinput --set-prop $deviceId 'Evdev Wheel Emulation Button' 2
xinput --set-prop $deviceId 'Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes' 6 7 4 5
```

---

- [You can add this](https://askubuntu.com/a/461173/349837) to a bash script and run it at login.
- Like with the wheel, with the same movement while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will zoom in/out the page. <kbd>Ctrl + 0</kbd> to reset.
- Ubuntu 20.04 use X by default. [Probably works also on Wayland](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/).
- Maybe better than Firefox *Autoscrolling*, easier to control.
- [Libinput at ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput)

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04; running the first of the proposed `evdev` commands gives me *"property 'Evdev Wheel Emulation' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format"*

Comment: @markAmery I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 too. Probably you are using libinput. List device properties. Don't forget upvote if it help you.

Comment: This is the best answer and should be accepted.

Comment: `evdev` worked like a charm. Just to note my mouse device was numbered `10` not `11`.

Comment: @piepi I edit my answer to be more clear, 11 was just in my case. Don't forget to upvote if you found it useful.

Comment: This worked gracefully. The next question is, how can I set this script to be run whenever the mouse is plugged in? Otherwise, if the mouse is plugged in *after* the script is run, the changes will not take effect.

Comment: @ArthurColombiniGusmão You can create a script [and use udev rules](https://askubuntu.com/a/347971).

Comment: Thanks @PabloBianchi. I forgot to mention that I already tried it and for some reason the script fails, saying that it wasn't capable of accessing Xserver. Maybe adding some delay to the script can serve as a workaround, but I'm not sure on how to that properly also.

Comment: Can't these properties be set in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, so there is no need for a script using udev?

Comment: If you want to see values before you start mucking around you can use `xinput list-props ##` where `##` is the device number from `xinput list`

Comment: This is great. Thanks @PabloBianchi

Comment: The commands using "Evdev" doesn't work for me on Arch Linux

Comment: after I release the mouse click, the content on clipboard is also pasted. Can I somehow not paste whatever was written on the clipboard when I release the middle button?

Answer (score 7):

### TLDR:

Use this flag on Chrome/Chromium/Electron or anything Chromium-based

```
--enable-blink-features=MiddleClickAutoscroll
```

> Make sure to close all Chrome instances before running this.

To make this permanent, you can edit the `.desktop` file and add this flag in the end of the `Exec=` line (Browsers typically have many `Exec=` lines for right click actions, the main one is under `[Desktop Entry]` but you might want to change them all).

> For Chrome, the desktop file can be found in this path:
> `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`

### Explanation:

The code for disabling middle mouse autoscroll on Linux/Mac is [here](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/057f3c9755e6226a74bb08d491037eed1a81a036/third_party/blink/renderer/core/exported/web_view_impl.cc#L1786). This basically says if it's running on Windows, enable this blink Runtime Enabled Feature.

[According to the Chromium wiki](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/RuntimeEnabledFeatures.md#command_line-switches) you can use `--{enable,disable}-blink-features` to enable or disable blink Runtime Enabled Features.

As found [here](https://niek.github.io/chrome-features/) the feature is called `MiddleClickAutoscroll` so that would be `--enable-blink-features=MiddleClickAutoscroll`.

The only caviar is this [warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxoVO.png) which appears when you use this flag. Other than that it works perfectly on Chrome/-ium, Chromium-based browsers (like Brave) and Electron apps (Discord, Slack, etc).

### Notes:

1. I only tested this on Linux but it might as well work on Mac the same way.
2. Using the `enable-features` and `blink-enable-features` flags is neither recommended nor supported by Chrome/Chromium or whatever you are using. This is why the warning message is displayed, these options are intended for testing use only. If you encounter any bugs after enabling this flag, make sure to disable it before sending a bug report.
3. It seems there is a reason this is disabled by default (on Linux at least). If you are using Xorg (x11) and you try to use autoscroll while a textbox is selected, it will paste the last selected text to it. A way to fix this is to ["disable" the selection clipboard](https://askubuntu.com/a/4644/811896).

Comment: Please note that for `--enable-blink-features=MiddleClickAutoscroll` to work you need to close all Chrome instances first. If you are trying this in a new window while you keep this one opened to also try the other answers, it won't work. **CLOSE ALL CHROME INSTANCES BEFORE RUNNING THIS!**. Also worth noting the chrome's executable file can be found at /opt/google/chrome/chrome in Ubuntu, so you would run `/opt/google/chrome/chrome --enable-blink-features=MiddleClickAutoscroll`

Comment: The path of the Chrome's desktop file is `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`

Answer (score 4):

I recommend another couple of addons, that allows "Scroll a page as if a scrollbar is under your mouse." I found that give us more control over the scroll move.

- For [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ScrollbarAnywhere/?src=userprofile)
- For [Chromium/Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scrollbar-anywhere/namcaplenodjnggbfkbopdbfngponici)

With both addons you just click and hold secondary button pressed to scroll pages moving the mouse up and down and even horizontally.

Comment: Extensions named as "Scrollbar Anywhere" is working better then "AutoScroll", because it doesn't blocking mouseDown js-event on website'spages if it needn't.

Answer (score -1):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and mouse wheel stopped working on one of my Chrome instances.  I followed the tip [here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-smooth-scrolling-feature-in-google-chrome/) and it works great.  When I go into the page `about::flags`, the "Smooth Scrolling" option was enabled. I disabled it and it works.