# configure Logitech Trackman Marble on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: mouse, 20.10, logitech

I am using i3 window manager and not sure how to configure my Trackman. I found this link but it's confusing: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_Marble_Mouse

Are there clear instructions somewhere on how to setup my mouse? More specifically I am interested in turning the small left button to act as a vertical scroller istead of the default (left navigation in the browser).

On Ubuntu 16.04 I used to add this to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-marblemouse.conf

```
  Section "InputClass"
      Identifier      "Marble Mouse"
      MatchProduct    "Logitech USB Trackball"
      MatchIsPointer  "on"
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
      Driver          "evdev"
      Option          "SendCoreEvents" "true"

      #  Physical buttons come from the mouse as:
      #     Big:   1 3
      #     Small: 8 9
      #
      # This makes left small button (8) into the middle click and scroll

      Option "Buttons"            "8"
      Option "ButtonMapping"      "1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 9"
      Option "EmulateWheel"       "true"
      Option "EmulateWheelButton" "8"
      Option "YAxisMapping"       "4 5"
      Option "XAxisMapping"       "6 7"

  EndSection
```

but the link above is talking about different file and different content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Logitech Marble trackball](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66253/how-to-configure-logitech-marble-trackball)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/263086.

Answer (score 0):

The following link is more Ubuntu specific for the Logitech Trackman Marble.  Hope this helps.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB