# Middle mouse button scrolling?

Tags: mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll, button

In ubuntu 20.04 middle mouse button scrolling doesn't working? But in windows 10 it works fine.

I am using Bluetooth intex mouse.

Comment: I use a standard USB mouse with 20.04 LTS and the middle scroll roller works perfectly well. [edit] your question if you are using something other than a standard mouse to explain more fully what your issue is.

Comment: i edited the question @24601

Comment: Run the command `xev`. Move the mouse pointer to the window displayed and rest it there. *Without moving the mouse or clicking any mouse button,* try to make small scroll actions. Note the messages displayed on the terminal window that you started the `xev` command. In my system the scroll down action displays `... button 5 ...` at the last line and the scroll up action displays `... button 4 ...`.

Comment: it display button 5 what should i do my middle mouse button scrolling is not working @FedonKadifeli

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome/Chromium middle mouse button for scroll Linux, Mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28150/chrome-chromium-middle-mouse-button-for-scroll-linux-mac)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'
```