# Smooth scroll in Geany?

Tags: scrolling, geany

I am using [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) in Ubuntu 20.04. Many applications have smooth scroll, but for some reason Geany doesn't. Is it possible to change this?

Comment: What is _smooth scroll_?

Comment: *Smooth scroll* is what is shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgvKGlKAXOU) for Gedit.

Comment: Per discussion on [a feature request on their GitHub](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1034), the underlying framework that Geany uses, Scintilla, does not support it.

Comment: Sorry, after my previous comment, I dug more into the weeds, and found that an external party did [commit a patch to Scintilla](https://github.com/KnIfER/Scintilla/commit/6cb2f94d84a3f2220f1301dd630975e40b2ff321) that would allow for smooth scrolling. As far as I can tell this was not included in the official release, however if you wanted to patch your own library, and implement it into Geany yourself, you could.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/868173/349837) might help you, will work with all your applications without the need of installing anything