# xinput --set-prop X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Tags: xorg, mouse

I am trying to get a better precision in scrolling with the mouse in Ubuntu 22.04 (Xorg session). I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/868173/823631) post and for my specific system I get

```
$ xinput list-props 12
Device 'Logitech T400':
    Device Enabled (189):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (191): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (325):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (326):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (327):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (328):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (329):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (330): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (331): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (332):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (333):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (334):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (335):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (336): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (337): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (338):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (339):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (340):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (341): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (342): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (310): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (311):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (312):    0, 0
    Device Node (313):  "/dev/input/event8"
    Device Product ID (314):    1133, 16422
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (343):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (344):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (345):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (346):    15
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (347):    1
```

It looks reasonable to change `libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance` by a smaller number. However, when I try `xinput --set-prop 12 "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 1` I get

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

no matter which value I try to set. How can I change these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

So first, according to https://man.archlinux.org/man/libinput.4.en#SCROLL_PIXEL_DISTANCE , the HIGHER the number, the slower (more precise) is scrolling.

From my testing on PopOS, valid values must be in range [10, 50]. So you've almost got it, try:

```
xinput --set-prop 12 "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 50
```

The problem is, that this setting will be valid only for current session and will require to be re-applied on every login. As of now, I couldn't find a way to change the default value.

Comment: You reference two non Ubuntu OS in your answer. This is a Ubuntu only site. This is not an answer unless you can say for sure this works on the Ubuntu version the OP asked about.