# XInput Coordinate Transformation Matrix in xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, touchscreen

How do I set the Coordinate Transformation Matrix in xorg.conf?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation

Right now, I have it set in a script on startup, but ideally - I would like to be able to unplug the screen and plug it back in and the settings still be used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figured it out by looking in the source:

```
Option "TransformationMatrix" "0.36 0 0.64 0 1 0 0 0 1"
```