# How to use a touchscreen in a multi-monitor setting with Wayland?

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen, wayland

I would like to connect an external touchscreen to my laptop (Ubuntu 18.10, GNOME).

The touchscreen works fine when used as the only monitor (disabling Laptop screen). However, I would like to use the two monitors side-by-side.

What I already tried (and failed):

- Rearrange monitors: Touch operations always go to the built-in monitor, independent of the monitor layout.
- Setting `WL_OUTPUT` for the USB touch input in `udev` ([as seen in that 
  Tizen multi-monitor multi-touch documentation](https://wiki.tizen.org/IVI/Mapping_multiple_touchscreen_Wayland)): It is being ignored (in fact, the `weston` source contains no reference to `WL_OUTPUT`; also, `weston-info` does not give any monitor names and I doubt the monitor names from `xrandr` are useful in this context).
- Trying `touchpad-edge-detector`: Detects coordinates fine, but did not give any hints how to proceed.
- Trying `xinput_calibrator`: Complains about illegal touch operations.
- Using [`weston-touch-calibrator`](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2018-March/037610.html): Did not find it anywhere
- I have not yet tried manually creating `LIBINPUT_CALIBRATION_MATRIX`, as I do not think this is the "good" way to do it (probably depends on monitor resolutions/arrangements/availability).

I think the Tizen approach would be best, i.e., to tell Weston which touchpad is related to which touchscreen. However, I cannot find a way to do this, including reading the `libinput` documentation and grepping through the `weston` source.

Having more than one monitor should not be so weird today anymore, should it? And having a touchscreen shouldn't be either?

Comment: It is not clear at all what is the behaviour you want. Have you tried this in Windows?

Comment: @Nicolay77 (a) I don't have any machines with Windows installed. (b) With multiple monitors in "join displays" mode, one of which is a touch screen, the touch events are mapped to a rectangle embedding both joint monitors. So, touching the middle of the touch screen will translate to an event in the middle of the combined (joint) display area, which is not under my finger. Please let me know if this makes it clearer.

Comment: I don't think the issue has anything to do with Wayland in particular, as this fixed it for me:  https://askubuntu.com/a/773812/140374

Comment: I have a similar observation with gnome under wayland. When mirroring is used, it works well. If the external display is used as an independent monitor,touch  events are sent to the internal laptop display, rather than to the external display, I confess I am using gnome 41 under fedora right now.

Comment: Marcel, I have been searching an answer for this question too, but no luck. Many people are using multiple touchscreens in their system, now they test on Ubuntu 20, and having a touch map to wrong video monitor.
Why Wayland does not provide any solution for this?

Comment: On X, it would just be a matter of using xinput --map-to-output and providing the screen and touchscreen devices. But on Wayland? Not sure how you'd do that. Adding a bounty as this is a good question that needs an answer.

Comment: Actually, not adding a bounty after all, since I think this is a lack of functionality, not a tricky problem. It might be worth a bug report on Launchpad.net.

Answer (score 1):

[Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/touchscreen#Wayland/Weston) documents this to be unsupported:

> Wayland does not currently have a known method to lock touching to a specific display in any environment other than sway [...]

(Sway is a Wayland compositor for i3).