# How can I save my touchpad configurations?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I have changed my touchpad configurations to:

```
xinput set-prop "13" "Synaptics Finger" 50 50 255
xinput set-prop "13" "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" 20 20
true
```

How can I save those configurations? Every time I reboot, they are set to default again.

Comment: With all the different X implementations, The most reliable method is to [Add *xinput* command to your startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/a/461173/767056)