# left click randomly triggers right click action

Tags: mouse, input-devices, input

I have issue with left click randomly triggering right click action. For example I click with left button in chrome but it opens context menu. This issue happens in any apps.

Ubuntu 20.04.
Dell G5 5590

I tried to solve it with multiple advices I found, like:

- adding this content to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpad` file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  post)
    /sbin/rmmod i2c_hid && /sbin/modprobe i2c_hid 
  ;;
esac
```

and `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` command...

- or with adding `blacklist psmouse` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
  and executing `sudo update-initramfs -u`
  or also:

```
modprobe drm_kms_helper
echo N> /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
echo 'drm_kms_helper' >> /etc/modules-load.d/local.conf
echo "options drm_kms_helper poll=N" >> /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
```

but nothing helped. Do you have any other suggestions?
note: I'm sure it's not mouse problem, as I tried 3 different mouses (Microsoft Optical Mouse, B200, Logitech M110s)

Tried `xev`, at left click I got this log:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x92b, subw 0x0, time 1882500, (118,76), root:(340,290),
    state 0x110, button 3, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x92b, subw 0x0, time 1882510, (118,76), root:(340,290),
    state 0x510, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x92b, subw 0x0, time 1882510, (118,76), root:(340,290),
    state 0x410, button 3, same_screen YES

ButtonPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x92b, subw 0x0, time 1882694, (118,76), root:(340,290),
    state 0x10, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x92b, subw 0x0, time 1882840, (118,76), root:(340,290),
    state 0x110, button 1, same_screen YES
```

Comment: Have you considered a hardware issue? Replace the mouse with another pointing device and see if the problem persists.

Comment: > note: I'm sure it's not mouse problem, as I tried 3 different mouses (Microsoft Optical Mouse, B200, Logitech M110s)

I think replacing mouse will not help....... I already did it 3 times, I'm sure 4th mouse will do the same....

Answer (score 1):

You already confirmed that the issue is not the external mouse (very unlikely with 3 different mouses you have already tested).

So I suspect your integrated touchpad and it's associated buttons is the cause of the spurious clicks.

You may be able to either disable the touchpad driver to check that, or even open your laptop and unplug it mechanically.

As long as you do not de-couple the possible sources of clicks, you won't find the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for answer.... I have touchpad disabled in settings,... will try to uninstall/disable driver. Can you help me how?

Comment: oh, ok I tried `xinput --disable <id_of_touchpad>` will see if it works now fine.

Comment: after testing for 2 hours of a lot of clicking, it seems like this really fixed issue... thank you so much

Comment: after week, issue is back.... grr..... I don't really know what else can be problem. Touchpad is disconnected, mouse is properly working (tested with other devices, tried multiple mouses), yet, Ubuntu on my Dell laptop is still randomly triggering right click action on left click... I will maybe reinstall Ubuntu when I will have time.

Comment: Hm, strange. is the setting `xinput --disable <id_of_touchpad>` permanent, I mean does it survive a reboot? Does the problem happen independently from any program, or does it happen in a particular application?

Comment: it happens randomly, independently from any program.

Comment: Maybe you need to persist your `xinput --disable <id_of_touchpad>` setting to be in place everytime after sleep or reboot, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20298/how-to-make-xinput-settings-persist-after-devices-are-unplugged-replugged-and)

Comment: Now I have other similiar issue.... instead of right click... randomly click doesn't happen.... from ten left clicks, only 4 clicks were actually detected. Ugh....

Answer (score 0):

In setting mouse and touchpad, general, primary button, select left.

[image]

Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: That's ofc selected already... it's not like I have switched those buttons... it's that left click randomly triggers action of right click... right click always do right click action.