# Why there is considerable difference in moving speed between touchpad and usb mouse?

Tags: usb, mouse, touchpad

Why there is considerable difference in moving speed between touchpad and usb mouse? The mouse is ok, but touchpad is very slow. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't have a real answer, but you might find [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3719/how-can-i-set-different-sensitivities-for-two-mice-at-the-same-time) useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust your speed settings a couple ways. **First**, use *System > Preferences > Mouse*.

[image]

**Second**, install [gpointing-device-settings](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gpointing-device-settings) so you can use *System > Preferences > Pointing device*. The advantage here is that you should be able to set different speeds for your different mice and touchpads.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that this is because of the drivers for the mouse and the touchpad. Try going to your touchpads website and see if there are any installation documents for Ubuntu.

It may work, but it may not, it's just a hunch actually.